# Is it against the rules that a user has two different profiles?

Tags: discussion

Due to some very peculiar grammar typo and the style of the answers, and some things more, I strongly suspect that one user has two different profiles with different names. I don't have anything against that person, but I wonder, is not that agaist the rules? Having more than one profile would allow a user to vote for himself several times, or to abnormally punish another user by downvoting him from all his profiles. Isn't there any kind of automated cross-checking or IP control or something similar for these things in Stackexchange? Just a thought...

(Well, the IP doesn't proof anything, you can have for example two students sharing a flat and the internet connection)

Comment: They are called *sock puppets* if used to cheat.

Comment: HA ha ha, nice name. But, no control against that?

Answer (score 7):

It's not against the rules exactly, no. However if you use multiple accounts for nefarious means then yes, it would be.

For instance; you could have alternative profiles for asking / answering questions you don't want associated with your main account (if you have an account on Careers, for instance).

However, if you start voting for yourself using your other accounts **then that is very much against the rules** and it is highly likely you will be found out, have the accounts merged together and then be suspended for a period of time.

Comment: We don't typically merge accounts anymore; it's too difficult to undo a merge if a mistake occurs.  We generally just delete the sock account.

Comment: But, what happens if I have a profile with my real name in, say, biology, and want to have a second profile to ask basic questions in biology, and in other branches in which I am nearly ignorant. I want to be able to post my simple, amateur questions with no fear of my future employers to see them and think that I am stupid. As long as I NEVER vote for myself or up/down vote anybody from both profiles, can I do that safely? I don't want to miss my main profile, it has good points, buy I am learning new things from time to time and I like to post my basic questions about many fields here...

Comment: @Mephisto JonW already stated that is OK, and it is.

Comment: Well, but he is not a moderator. Your diamond gives certain value to the confirmation to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Mephisto rest assured that most often, if people give wrong information on Meta, we downvote the crap out of them. :p But kidding aside, the same is confirmed by one of the founders of the site in the dupe.

Comment: HA HA HA, I love that expression, that I immediately incorpore to my english baggage: *we downvote the crap out of them!* I really love stackexchange sites...

Comment: @Mephisto I am a moderator, but on ux.stackexchange not Meta Stackoverflow.